# sending notification even if there is no update done in the server

Tags: android, sql-server, push-notification

My problem is that the code should send notification only when i add a new offer by checking in the server every 20seconds where offerNumber > the offer number we already have and when offer number become > offer number that we have, it sends notification with new offer added.
But, it sends notification every 20 seconds even if there is no update .. I need to send notification only when offerNumber>offerNum

```
public class service extends IntentService {

    ResultSet resultSet;
    String offerTitle;
    public static int offerNum = 0;
    String msg="";
    ConnectSQL connectSQL = new ConnectSQL();
    public static boolean ServiceIsRun = false;

    public service() {
        super("MyWebRequestService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent workintent) {

        while (ServiceIsRun) {
            try {
                resultSet = connectSQL.RunSearch("SELECT * FROM offerdetails where offernumber> " + offerNum + " ", this);

                if (resultSet.next()) {
                    msg= resultSet.getString(1).toString();
                    offerNum = resultSet.getInt(9);
                }

               Intent intent = new Intent();
                //set the action that will receive our broadcast
                intent.setAction("com.example.Broadcast");
                // add data to the bundle
                intent.putExtra("msg", msg);
                // send the data to broadcast
                sendBroadcast(intent);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(20000);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Polling the database every 20 seconds does not seem like the right approach -- some mechanism using triggers seems more appropriate.